# Updating subdocument node multiple record - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update the mongodb collection document, I need to update the value of latest to "0" only its values is "1"

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56411fda7f8b9a4503adeb1e"), 
    "campaigns" : [
        {

            "latest" : NumberInt (0),            
            "timestamp" : "2015-11-10 00:16:10",
          "name" : "camp1",
        }, 
        {
            "latest" : NumberInt(1), 
        "timestamp" : "2015-11-11 00:16:10",
            "name" : "camp2",
        },
      {
            "latest" : NumberInt(1), 
        "timestamp" : "2015-11-12 00:16:10",
            "name" : "camp3",
        }

    ]
}
```

**Query :**

```
db.test.update({"_id" : ObjectId("56411fda7f8b9a4503adeb1e"),'campaigns.latest' : 1},{'$set':{"campaigns.$.latest":0}},{'multi':true});
```

it updates only the first matches not all, Please can anyone help us to solve.

Comment: If campaigns length is not fixed then you cannot do this in a single query

Comment: campaigns length is not fixed

Comment: Your answer is definitely in there. Please read carefully those answers.